# symfony2 2.3 missing FormBuilder::addValidator() how to adapt to FormBuilderInterface?

Tags: validation, symfony, formbuilder

Seems that the addValidator function of the FormBuilder is gone in the recent version of symfony2. Anyonw know how to rewrite that functionality?

Here's my 2.0 code:

```
    $builder-> addValidator(new CallbackValidator(function(FormInterface $form){
      $email = $form->get('email')->getData();      
        if (empty( $email )) {
          $form['email']->addError(new FormError("Du måste ange en epostadress för användaren"));
        }
    }));
```

I understand that the FormBuilder was replaced by "FormBuilderInterface" in 2.1, but I am still a bit confused as to what steps I need to take to rewrite this functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Symfony 2.1 `FormValidatorInterface` which is implemented by `CallbackValidator` is deprecated, and removed in 2.3.

[Upgrade to 2.1 file](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/UPGRADE-2.1.md) gives solution:

> The interface `FormValidatorInterface` was deprecated and will be removed in Symfony 2.3.
>
> If you implemented custom validators using this interface, you can substitute them by event listeners listening to the `FormEvents::POST_BIND` (or any other of the `*BIND` events). In case you used the `CallbackValidator` class, you should now pass the callback directly to `addEventListener`.